# How server automatically send data to user

Tags: java, php, webserver

I decide to make a chat room. (Server side is PHP or Java). First thing, I use AJAX base on this idea:

> 1) both users will often send request to server to take the latest
>   message.
>
> 2) when one user types message and enter, the text will be send to
>   server, and server save it to database and waiting for other users
>   take it.

the disadvantage of this ways is it not efficient. It's not very problem in chat program, but I decide to make some other function such as draw on screen and share between people.

So, I decide to use other ways. Here is new way :

> 1) when users connect to chat room, there are "some ways" to remain
>   them.
>
> 2) when some one send text to server, the server will "automatically"
>   send this text to the rest of users.

I base on `Observer Pattern` of Gof. And this way works better than other. But the problem I have met in this new way is :

> 1) what "information" about user will be save. (IP address, ... ?)
>
> 2) how to send to user ? (when users don't have request to server).

Please tell me the solution, please. And better, if it's more detail in Java or PHP.

Comment: Research Asynchronous Javascript And XML (AJAX)

Comment: If you don't want to send requests to get info, you should look into HTML 5 sockets. These only work on HTML 5 compliant browsers though.

Comment: You can use opensource chat application [link](http://blogupstairs.com/8-free-open-source-chat-application-based-ajax/),then you can build your application according to your application required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use **Session** to identify and store information about the connected users. The main work is done by the server, and many web framework (PHP, Java, or other) can handle this for you.